# Can a radio antenna damage a phone?

Tags: antenna

I am currently attending a radio technology course. We continuously work on radio sets that are sometimes used as manpacks by the Army. In order to learn how to operate them we work in close proximity to the sets and their antennas.

The antennas are generally whip type or long rods. Such as these :

[image]
[image]

The radio sets generally output around 25-50W in the 30-90MHz frequency range. Can that possibly cause damage to my iPhone?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross-post from [EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/346138/11683).

Comment: @DaveTweedN3AOA I am sorry! I am new around here. I'll keep this in mind for the future. I was trying to get different opinions from people of different fields.

Comment: @TheBrokenBee More info — It's okay to get your question _moved_ from another site if you don't get an adequate answer and it's on-topic (flag for a moderator to do it, or delete and post it yourself if there are no answers), or to post substantially different questions for different audiences, but not to post multiple identical questions (because then people may waste effort to write redundant answers).